# Encoding problems Datatables

Tags: encoding, datatables, special-characters, utf8-decode

I'm using datatables to show my records on my site, but when i'm entering in my input field those characters: ( € OR ‘ OR ’ ) my datatable isn't showing those characters. All other special characters are shown.

The rest of the website is showing all characters including: ( € OR ‘ OR ’ )?

```php
static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
{
    $out = array();
    for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
        $row = array();

        for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {

            $column = $columns[$j];

            // Is there a formatter?
            if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
            }
            else {
                $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
            }
        }

        $row = self::encodeutf8($row);

        $out[] = $row;
    }
    return $out;
}

private static function encodeutf8($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = self::encodeutf8($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

I added by myself the function : encodeutf8. I did this because before that, my table crashed everytime when i added an item with special characters in it.

My columns looks like this:

```php
$columns = [
        ['db' => 'foto1', 'dt' => 0, 'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
            if($d == "") {
                return "";
            }
            return "<img class='thumb' src='/" . $d . "'/>";
        }],
        ['db' => 'p_categorie', 'dt' => 1],
        ['db' => 'p_genre', 'dt' => 2],
        ['db' => 'p_aantal', 'dt' => 3],
        ['db' => 'p_prijs', 'dt' => 4, 'formatter' => function($d, $row){
            if($d == '0.00'){
                return "N.o.t.k";
            }
            else{
                return "&euro;" .$d.",-";
            }
        }],
        ['db' => 'w_naam', 'dt' => 5],
        ['db' => 'p_artiest', 'dt' => 6, 'formatter' => function($d, $row){
            if($d != ''){
                return $d;
            }
            else{
                return "N.V.T.";
            }
        }],
        ['db' => 'p_medium', 'dt' => 7],
        ['db' => 'p_titel', 'dt' => 8],
        ['db' => 'p_conditie', 'dt' => 9],
        ['db' => 'p_bijzonderheid', 'dt' => 10],
        ['db' => 'p_datum', 'dt' => 11, 'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
            return "<a style='text-decoration:none; color:black;' title='".$d."'>".date('d-M-Y', strtotime($d))."</a>";
        }],
        ['db' => 'p_id', 'dt' => 12, 'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
            return "<a data-id='" . $d . "' href='/productdetail?p_id=" . $d . "'>Bekijk</a>";
        }],
    ];
```

I am looking forward to any reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using a diversion of [**ssp.class.php**](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) using your own database-connection. Your problem is that you not have defined a proper charset for your connection - it should be set to `utf8`.

I cannot know what underlying connection you are using, but you must setup the charset immediately after you have established the connection.

- mysql

```php
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

- mysqli

```php
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8');  
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

- PDO

```php
    $dbh = new PDO($name, $username, $password);
    $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: This did the trick after i deleted my own function for encoding! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying on my post,

I am indeed using a standard SSP file, my connection looks like:

```
static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
{
    try {
        $db = @new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
            $sql_details['user'],
            $sql_details['pass'],
            array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
        );
        //$db->exec("set names utf8");
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        self::fatal(
            "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
            "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
        );
    }

    return $db;
}**strong text**
```

I've tried to add the ($db->exec), but when i add it, my characters are
way different then my input was.:

```
muziek  Drumandbass 2   €10.00,-    "hoi " hallo    Â¿Ã§Â´Â¶Â¬Â»Â«ÃÂ¥  lp  Ã¤Ã¥Ã©Â®Ã¾Ã¼ÃºÃ­Ã³Ã¶Ã¡ÃÃ°Ã¸Ã¦Â©Ã±Âµ    Goede staat     22-Oct-2015 Bekijk
muziek  Classicrock 1   €10.00,-    %@%@":blabla    Â´Ã¦Â©Ã±ÂµÃ§Â¿  cd  Â¡Â²Â³Â¤â¬Â¼Â½Â¾ââÂ¥ÃÃ¤Ã¥Ã©Â®Ã¾Ã¼ÃºÃ­Ã³Ã¶Â«Â»Ã¡ÃÃ°Ã¸Â¶Â´ Goede staat     21-Oct-2015 Bekijk
```

Instead of:

```
 muziek Drumandbass 2   €10.00,-    "hoi " hallo    ¿ç´¶¬»«×¥   lp  äåé®þüúíóöáßðøæ©ñµ  Goede staat     22-Oct-2015 Bekijk
 muziek Classicrock 1   €10.00,-    %@%@":blabla    ´æ©ñµç¿ cd  ¡²³¤¼½¾¥×äåé®þüúíóö«»áßðø¶´  Goede staat     21-Oct-2015 Bekijk
```

The last two rows, are almost good, only the € and ‘,’  characters are missing.